# Configure API URL in Angular application

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-config

I am currently using proxy.conf.json to configure API url for development. I believe it only works on the local server. How can I configure the API url when deploying it on UAT and Production server? I would like to change the API url on the server without re-building the entire application.

**proxy.conf.json:**

```
{
    "/api": {
      "target": "http://api_server:88",
      "secure": false,
      "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
    },
      "changeOrigin": true
    }
  }
```

**api.service.ts:**

```
get<T>(params: any = {}) : Observable<T> {
    return this.http.get<T>("/api/data", {params: params});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way has been working great for us:

1. Create a custom HTTP Service and build a function that will check the current URL.

**custom-http.service.ts** <- You can name this specific to your company / app name

```js
@Injectable()
export class CustomHttpService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    public getCurrentEnvironment(): string {
        const host = window.location.origin;
        let env = "";
        switch(host) {
            case 'http://localhost:4200': {
                env = 'LOCALDEV';
                break;
            }
            case 'https://my-test-site.azurewebsites.net': {
                env = 'TEST';
                break;
            }
            case 'https://my-prod-site.azurewebsites.net': {
                env = 'PROD';
                break;
            }
            case 'https://customdomain.com': {
                env = 'PROD';
                break;
            }
            default: {
                env = 'PROD';
                break;
            }

        }
        return env;
    }

    public get(url: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(url);
    }

    public getWithHeader(url: string, header: HttpHeaders): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(url, {headers: header});
    }

    public post(url: string, body: any): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post(url, body);
    }

    public put(url: string, body: any): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.put(url, body);
    }

    public delete(url: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.delete(url);
    }
}
```

You can call getCurrentEnvironment() from any where in your app to know which environment you are on.

2. Create a URL helper service, this will pass in the correct API url for your specific environment.

```js
@Injectable()
export class URLHelper {
    constructor(private httpService: CustomHttpService) {

    }

    private env: string = this.httpService.getCurrentEnvironment();
    private Server: string = this.getServerUrl(this.env);

    getServerUrl(env: string): string {
        let server = "";
        switch (env) {
            case "LOCALDEV": {
                server = "http://localhost/project/";
                break;
            }
            case "TEST": {
                server = "https://my-test-site-api.azurewebsites.net/";
                break;
            }
            case "PROD": {
                server = "https://my-prod-site-api.azurewebsites.net/";
                break;
            }
            default: {
                console.error('No Env Found');
                server = "https://my-prod-site-api.azurewebsites.net/";
            }
        }
        return server;
    }

    // Here you will define all the API endpoints your app will use and 'this.Server ' will contain the proper host API server url at runtime for each environment.
    public User = this.Server + 'api/User';
```

3. Usage. To use this now, all you need to do is in any of your feature module services, add CustomHttpService and URLHelper into the constructor

```js
@Injectable()
export class AdminService {

    constructor(private urlHelper: URLHelper, private httpService: CustomHttpService) { }

    getUser(): Observable<any> {
        return this.httpService.get(this.urlHelper.User);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Brian. It looks like a good option. How do you specify which environment to use on a server? Is it during the build time? e.g. ng serve -env=TEST?

Comment: The getCurrentEnvrionment looks at the current URL in the browswer `window.location.origin`. All you need to do is `ng serve` and open your broswer to http://localhost:4200 and the getCurrentEnvrionment will return LOCALDEV and your API host will use `http://localhost/project/` in this case. You don't have to do anything extra.

Comment: i see, makes sense. The only downside is any url change will require rebuilding the angular application while it should really be a config change. Do you agree?

Comment: URLs should not be changing often and yes, if you add a new environment or change the UI host / API host, it will require a code push but that is also very minimal.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I am thinking to use a json file in assets folder and get the url from the JSON file so it can be changed without compiling. Do you see any downside using the approach?

Comment: Nope, that will work just fine too. Makes it easier to update without code push.

Answer (score 1):

The proxy configurations in the `proxy.conf.json` file is for your Webpack dev server to run your Angular application locally using `ng serve` command. It should not be used for Production and staging environments. You can find details about this in the official [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server) page.

If you want to add a similar feature to your NodeJs or any other server which is hosting your angular application, check if API gateway plugins are available for the server you are using.

Check this [article](https://www.nginx.com/learn/api-gateway/) if you are not aware of API gateways.

Comment: Thanks Shravan. I am deploying it on IIS. I was wondering if there is any easier option than adding additional Nginx dependency. I am expecting it should be something built-in  as it is a very basic ask.